# collect form data of every time submit in json

Tags: javascript, json

I am using a code in which, when we submit the form, gets all form input field value in **JSON** format.

But I want to collect all time data i.e. every time we submit the form it should be collected and display result. In the present situation I am getting only one time submit:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};


$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        var ks = $('#answer').val().split("\n");
        var formData = $('form').serializeObject();
        $.extend(formData, { answerss : ks});
        var result = JSON.stringify(formData);  
        $("#result").html(result);
return false;
    });
});
```

current output:

```
{
    "question": "1+1",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "answer": "1\r\n2\r\n3\r\n4",
    "mandatory": "yes",
    "json_data": "",
    "answerss": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aw339kwo/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an array say '`resultFormArray`' and each time you submit `push` it to this array. i.e `resultFormArray.push(formData)` where formData is your `obj` having the current submited data. Now the `resultFormArray` will contain all your form datas.

```
 var resultFormArray=[ ];                                                                         
        $(function() {
            $('form').submit(function(e) {
                var ks = $('#answer').val().split("\n");
                var formData = $('form').serializeObject();
                $.extend(formData, { answerss : ks});                                            
                resultFormArray.push(formData); 
                console.log(resultFormArray) /*will have all the form  datas in this*/
              /*var result = JSON.stringify(formData);  
               $("#result").html(result);    */                                                               
              return false;
            }); 
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhi for reply,can u  give an working  example

Comment: How to print current output in div

Comment: $("#result").html(resultFormArray);